# How to find text and replace it by image in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I want to make custom smileys plugin for CKeditor. There is one thing i can't do. If user writes to input "`:-)`", editor will automatically convert to "`<img src='img/smiley.png' />`". How to do it?

Comment: There must be some configuration option inside CKEditor somewhere to specify which image should be used for which emoticon…

Comment: Nope, you don't get it. I am not using any of plugin right now. I want to make new one because it doesn't fit my needs. All i want to do is catch OnKeyPress event in CKeditor and look for some of `:-)` and replace it by image. Exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do it manually by listening to the `change` event and every time that it fires, search the content for ":-)" and replace it with the image.